# Filter out some key in using mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I want to query my mongodb collection and filter out some keys. Sounds simple?
Have a look at one of the documents of my collection:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("56bb06a53db26f349d29842c"),
"TIME": NumberLong(1455097500000),
"MID": {
    "STATUS": {
        "C_16": {
            "R_31": {
                "FAIL": 24
            }
        }
    },
    "B30": {
        "STATUS": {
            "C_16": {
                "R_31": {
                    "FAIL": 6
                }
            }
        },
        "BB": {
            "STATUS": {
                "C_16": {
                    "R_31": {
                        "FAIL": 3
                    }
                }
            },
            "MID30HNSRP01": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "WB": {
            "MID30HNSWBRP03": {
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "STATUS": {
                "C_16": {
                    "R_31": {
                        "FAIL": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
},
"STATUS": {
    "C_16": {
        "R_31": {
            "FAIL": 318
        }
    }
},
"SLC": {
    "STATUS": {
        "C_16": {
            "R_31": {
                "FAIL": 27
            }
        }
    },
    "B40": {
        "STATUS": {
            "C_16": {
                "R_31": {
                    "FAIL": 6
                }
            }
        },
        "WB": {
            "SLC40HNSWBRP02": {
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "STATUS": {
                "C_16": {
                    "R_31": {
                        "FAIL": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "BB": {
            "SLC40HNSRP01": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "STATUS": {
                "C_16": {
                    "R_31": {
                        "FAIL": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "B34": {
        "WB": {
            "STATUS": {
                "C_16": {
                    "R_31": {
                        "FAIL": 6
                    }
                }
            },
            "SLC34HNSWBRP03": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "SLC34HNSWBRP02": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "STATUS": {
            "C_16": {
                "R_31": {
                    "FAIL": 9
                }
            }
        },
        "BB": {
            "SLC34HNSRP01": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "STATUS": {
                "C_16": {
                    "R_31": {
                        "FAIL": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "B39": {
        "WB": {
            "SLC39HNSWBRP02": {
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "STATUS": {
                "C_16": {
                    "R_31": {
                        "FAIL": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "STATUS": {
            "C_16": {
                "R_31": {
                    "FAIL": 6
                }
            }
        },
        "BB": {
            "SLC39HNSRP01": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "STATUS": {
                "C_16": {
                    "R_31": {
                        "FAIL": 3
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "B46": {
        "BB": {
            "STATUS": {
                "C_16": {
                    "R_31": {
                        "FAIL": 3
                    }
                }
            },
            "SLC46HNSRP01": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "STATUS": {
            "C_16": {
                "R_31": {
                    "FAIL": 6
                }
            }
        },
        "WB": {
            "STATUS": {
                "C_16": {
                    "R_31": {
                        "FAIL": 3
                    }
                }
            },
            "SLC46HNSWBRP02": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "C_16": {
                        "R_31": {
                            "FAIL": 3
                        }
                    }
                },
                "IPGW": {
                    "STATUS": {
                        "C_16": {
                            "R_31": {
                                "FAIL": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I want to query this collection, let say `XYZ`, but don't want the keys named IPGW at any level of the document.

The only thing which is consistent in this schem is:
The `IPGW` key is present at a fixed path like `A.B.C.D.IPGW` but `A,B,C,D` could be anything.

Is their any way to do it ? Aggregation/Projection ?

If not, I will go on to fetch the documents as they are and then remove the keys manually through my Java script

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: This is a horrible structure. Sorry, but no other way to say it.It's a classic case where the "key names" have been used to actually represent "data" points. Though MongoDB is schemaless and flexible, it is still intended to be used as a "database" first and foremost. So you are always better off using consistent property names and rather then use the things that are representative of queryable values as actuall "data". You could use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) to traverse the document and match conditions, but this is very inefficient.

Comment: You would be far better off redesigning the storage with "database" in mind and particularly your usage patterns.

Comment: Agreed. But changing the structure is out of my discretion. Moreover, I've found a workaround for my problem. Thanks :-)